# How to check for unknown registers in verilog

Tags: verilog

When getting three inputs from the console, I am wondering how to check and 'warn' the user that a register may not have been initialized.

to do this I am trying:

```
flag = $value$plusargs("a=%b", a);
if (flag != 0 && flag != 1) begin
    $display("a might not be initialized");
end
flag = $value$plusargs("b=%b", b);
flag = $value$plusargs("c=%b", c);

#1 $display("a=%b b=%b c=%b z=%b", a, b, c, z);
```

However with my limited knowledge I am having a difficult time figuring out what to do. When I run my compiled code with no paramaters I get:

a = x, b = x, c = x, z = x;

but no warning, even though the flag(a) is clearly not 1 and not 0

Comment: did you mean that it was not initialized because a single '+' arg has been  missing or  because it was not initialized to a known value in the model as well? Is there only one +arg which could initialize the variable?  I am a bit confused by the 'might' keyword in your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flag` returns true(1) if `$value$plusargs` finds `+a=value` on the command line and sets the value of `a`. So you want

```
if (flag == 0) begin
    $display("a might not be initialized");
```

You can do this in one step

```
  if ( !$value$plusargs("a=%b", a) ) begin
        $display("a might not be initialized");
```

And if you use SystemVerilog, you can use `$warning()` instead of `$display()`.

Answer (score 0):

To compare with unknown value, you should use !== or === instead of != and ==